# More than 2 columns GroupBy on View

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, view

As you know we can only do groupby for two columns. Is there any way to groupby more than two columns (in SharePoint 2010)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. There is [a blog](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/01/sharepoint-group-by-on-more-than-2.html) that can help you with this but you need to use SharePoint Designer.

The main points are:

- It can't be done "out of the box" in the browser
- SharePoint Designer is needed to make the edits
- You need to convert the view web part to a SharePoint Designer Data Form Web Part
- You need a Sort and Group secret
- You need to fix the footer rows
- You need to manually add your totals, averages, counts etc

Comment: Without dataviewwebpart. I dont want to lose capabilities of listviewwebpart.